# Convert string having json to json or struct

Tags: json, go

I am getting this type of response from an API:

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "response": "[
    {
        "Id": 163,
        "Name": "Availability",
        "Path": "Performance|Tier1",
        "frequency": "ONE_MIN",
        "Values": [
            {
                "startTimeInMillis": 1571314200000,
                "occurrences": 1,
                "current": 1,
                "min": 0,
                "max": 0,
                "useRange": false,
                "count": 1,
                "sum": 1,
                "value": 1,
                "standardDeviation": 0
            },
            {
                "startTimeInMillis": 1571314260000,
                "occurrences": 1,
                "current": 1,
                "min": 0,
                "max": 0,
                "useRange": false,
                "count": 1,
                "sum": 1,
                "value": 1,
                "standardDeviation": 0
            },
            }
       ]
    }
]
}
```

I want to convert this into time series format. To do so first I am trying to unmarshal the response to this struct:

```
type App struct{
    ID     string   `json:"metric_id"`
    Name   string   `json:"metric_name"`
    Path   string   `json:"metric_path"`
    Frequency    string   `json:"frequency"`
    Values []string `json:"metric_values"`
}
```

I am doing this:

```
apprsp := App{}
fmt.Println(json.Unmarshal([]byte(ame.Response), &apprsp))
```

But I am getting error while `json.Unmarshal`. 
What I am trying to do is to generate a json of format:

```
{'time':'value','time1':'value2'}
```

Where `time`/`time1` and `value`/`value2` is `startTimeInMillis` and value from values array. 
What I am doing wrong while json unmarshal? What should be done to unmarshal the above data?

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type service.App

Comment: The JSON you pasted isn't valid. Can you double-check that it's *exactly* what you're receiving?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `App` structure is not even closely related to the json document you're trying to unmarshal. To unmarshal a json document, you have to have a Go structure that somewhat matches the structure of the underlying document.

```
type ResponseValue struct {
    StartTime int64 `json:"startTimeMillis"`
    // other elements of Values here, if you're interested in them
}

type Response struct {
  Id int `json:"Id"`
  Name string `json:"Name"`
  Path string `json:"Path"`
  Frequency string `json:"frequency"`
  Values []ResponseValue `json:"Values"`
}

type Body struct {
  Response []Response `json:"response"`
}

var data Body
json.Unmarshal([]byte(ame.Response),&data)
```

Then, you can extract the time series from `data`.

Answer (score 1):

As the one above me just said your mapping from your json to the struct is wrong.
An easy way to find the write mapping is to use this tool https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/
It enables you to map json to an auto generated struct.

here is your response struct

```
type Response struct {
    ID        int    `json:"Id"`
    Name      string `json:"Name"`
    Path      string `json:"Path"`
    Frequency string `json:"frequency"`
    Values    []struct {
        StartTimeInMillis int64 `json:"startTimeInMillis"`
        Occurrences       int   `json:"occurrences"`
        Current           int   `json:"current"`
        Min               int   `json:"min"`
        Max               int   `json:"max"`
        UseRange          bool  `json:"useRange"`
        Count             int   `json:"count"`
        Sum               int   `json:"sum"`
        Value             int   `json:"value"`
        StandardDeviation int   `json:"standardDeviation"`
    } `json:"Values"`
}
```